# Prove that $\text{esssup}|f|<\infty\iff \text{esssup}f<\infty, \text{essinf}f>-\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measure space. Let $f\colon X\to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ a measurable function we define:

$$\text{esssup}f=\inf\{\alpha\in\mathbb{R}\;|\; f(x)\le \alpha\; \text{a.e.}\; \text{in}\;X\}$$
$$\text{essinf}f=\sup\{\alpha\in\mathbb{R}\;|\; f(x)\ge \alpha\; \text{a.e.}\; \text{in}\;X\}$$

I must prove that $$\text{esssup}|f|<\infty\iff \text{esssup}f<\infty, \text{essinf}f>-\infty$$

We start with $(\Leftarrow)$. Let $M:=\text{esssup}|f|<\infty$, then $|f(x)|\le M$ a.e. in $X$ and then, in particular, $f(x)\le M$ a.e. in $X$. Therefore $$M\in \{\alpha\in\mathbb{R}\;|\; f(x)\le \alpha\; \text{a.e.}\; \text{in}\;X\}$$ and then $\text{esssup}f<\infty$. For $\text{essinf}f>-\infty$ we consider the fact that $f(x)>-M$.

It's correct? Could you give me some suggestion for the other implication $(\Rightarrow)$?

Comment: Note that $-|f| \leqslant f \leqslant |f|$, and that $\mathrm{essinf}(-g) = - \mathrm{esssup}(g)$ for $g\geqslant 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, what you did is correct.

Now, suppose that $\operatorname{esssup}f=M_1<\infty$ and that $\operatorname{essinf}f=M_2>-\infty$. Take a number $M$ with $M\geqslant|M_1|$ and $M\geqslant|M_2|$. In particular, $M_1\leqslant M$, and therefore $f(x)\leqslant M$ a. e. And $M_2\geqslant -M$, and therefore $f(x)\geqslant -M$ a. e. So, $\bigl|f(x)\bigr|\leqslant M$ a. e. It follows that $\operatorname{esssup}|f|<\infty$.

Comment: Thanks. Let me ask you a question about my solution. Why proved that $f(x)\le M$ a.e. can conclude immediately that $\text{esssup}f<\infty$? What condition excludes that the inf is not infinite?

Comment: Which definition of $\operatorname{esssup}$ do you use?

Comment: $$\text{esssup}f=\inf\{\alpha\in\mathbb{R}\;|\; f(x)\le \alpha\; \text{a.e.}\; \text{in}\;X\}$$

Comment: Then $\operatorname{esssup}f$ is the infimum of o set to which $M$ belongs. Therefore, it cannot be $+\infty$.

Comment: Can be $-\infty$?

Comment: Sure. That's what happens if $f(x)=-\infty$, for each real number $x$.