# $\text{esssup}|f|<\infty\implies \text{esssup}f\ne-\infty$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measure space. Let $f\colon X\to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ a measurable function we define:

$$\text{esssup}f=\inf\{\alpha\in\mathbb{R}\;|\; f(x)\le \alpha\; \text{a.e.}\; \text{in}\;X\}$$
$$\text{esssup}|f|=\inf\{\alpha\ge 0\;|\; |f(x)|\le \alpha\; \text{a.e.}\; \text{in}\;X\}$$

I know that if $\text{esssup}|f|<\infty$, then $\text{esssup}f<\infty.$

It can happen that $\text{esssup}|f|<\infty$, but $\text{esssup}f=-\infty$? If yes/no, why?

Comment: Can't we apply the thing you already know to $-f$ ?

Comment: You need to do some work. If $\operatorname{ess} \sup f = -\infty$ then $f(x) = -\infty$ for ae. $x$. Alternatively, if $s = \operatorname{ess} \sup |f| < \infty$ then $f(x) \in [-s-1,s+1]$ for ae. $x$. What can you conclude from that?

Comment: Since you already [know](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4741049/446262) that $\operatorname{esssup}|f|<\infty\iff\operatorname{esssup}f<\infty\text{ and }\operatorname{esssup}f>-\infty$, what is the point of asking this?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantosWe suppose that $M:=\text{esssup}|f|<\infty$, then $|f(x)|\le M$ a.e. in $X$ and then, in particular, $f(x)\le M$ a.e. in $X$. From this, can I conclude that $-\infty<\text{esssup}<\infty?$

Comment: No, we cannot. But from the fact that $f(x)\ge-M$ a. e., yes, we can.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933). Please re-read copper.hat's comment.

Comment: @copper.hat If $s=\text{esssup}|f|<\infty$, then $\text{esssup}f$ it can not be $-\infty$, because we have that $-s\le f(x)=-\infty$ a.e. Right?

Comment: @NatMath Yes. ${}$